# Best approach to replace onclick javascript button for classic

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, salesforce-classic

I have a requirement in which I have to make a button, that first checks values of some fields and then, if conditions are true, redirects to a visualforce. Something like this:

```
if(field != value){
   alert('error message')
}else{
  //redirect to visualforce
}
```

This is for salesforce classic, so, normally, I would use onclick javascript for this.
But, they asked to make it so it works for Lightning, BUT in the future, I mean, they wont migrate to Lightning right away.
Is there a simple alternative to onclick javascript for classic that achieves this, and would work on lighting? I found a way in which I would create a "OnClickJSUtilityController"  and implement an interface to perform the logic ([source](https://www.sfdcstuff.com/2018/06/alternatives-to-onclick-javascript.html)), but it seems a little too much for something so simple as to check a few fields.

Is there an alternative to this for classic? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a VF page associated to the button:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"
      action="{!IF(Account.Name<>'foo',
                   NULL,
                   URLFOR($Page.MyPage,Account.Id)
                  )}">
   <apex:pageMessage title="Mymessage" severity="error"/>
</apex:page>
```

The `NULL` in the IF means don't redirect anywhere, just render the page.

References

- [apex:page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm)
- [$Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_page.htm)
- [URLFOR](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm)
- [apex:pageMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessage.htm)

Comment: okay, nice solution, but how do I insert the message in case the condition is true? I know I don't want to redirect to the other page, but how do I show the custom error ?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace button URL:

```
/apex/ApexStart?a=accorto.ProjectLineNS&m=updateProject
&n=projectId&v={!accorto__Project__c.Id}
&r=/{!accorto__Project__c.Id}&q={!URLENCODE('Recalculate Project Actuals')}
```